# Getting reference error on naming controls - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reference, xname

I have a solution named Solution1, which has multiple projects named Project1, Project2 etc. In Project1, I have a usercontrol called "DesignElement". When I name the UserControl from the XAML, using the "x:Name" and then compile it, i get the following compile error:

**"The type or namespace name 'Project2 ' does not exist in the namespace 'Solution1.Project1.Project2' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"**

Where is this reference of Project2 coming in Project1? Why does this compile error arise? Also, if I am not going to use the "x:Name" in any controls, then the solution compiles and runs fine. Any help on the same is appreciated.

Comment: Does your UserControl have the same name as a namespace?  I've experienced that this causes confusion sometimes.

Comment: No, they dont have the same name as the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have two projects in the same solution doesn't mean that they can instantly see each other.

Here is the proper flow to making them see each other

> 1. Create a solution
> 2. Add projects
> 3. In project two right click on references in Solution Explorer and hit add reference
>
>    ^^^^^this is the step you missed^^^^
> 4. In the collumn on the left of the popup click solution
> 5. Choose project one
> 6. Add using or xmlns in your code to project one
> 7. reference project one's code

Comment: I dont want the projects to see each other, but when i name the controls, it automatically searches for the other project, which is not required.